# form set error is not working properly

Tags: 7

I am using Drupal 7

i am tracking login and setting errors but my error is not working properly

here is my code

```
  <?php 


    function zloginsecurity_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) 
    {
        switch ($form_id)  {
        case 'user_login':
        case 'user_login_block':
           $form['#validate'] = zloginsecurity_validators();
          break;
      }
    }

    function zloginsecurity_validators() {
        return array('user_login_name_validate', 'user_login_authenticate_validate', 'user_login_final_validate','zloginsecurity_validate');
    }

    function zloginsecurity_validate($form, &$form_state) {
           if (empty($form_state['uid'])) {
            //Check user Track Record 
            echo "hello"; 
     form_set_error('name', t('hello test'));
          }else {
              zloginsecurity_removeevent();     
            //Delete Track Records for Particualr user 
        }

    }




 ?>
```

it is not showing hello test, it is showing default message .  Can anybody tell me how to solve this issue.   simple echo is working

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In `form_set_error`, the first parameter should be form name, if you are not sure of the name, just leave empty.

```
form_set_error('', t('hello test'));
```

This should work just fine.

**UPDATED ANSWER**

If you would like to have only your validation and skip the rest of Drupal core's validation for that particular form, you can unset the validator function and inject your own.

```
unset($form['#validate']);
$form['#validate'][] = 'zloginsecurity_validators';
```

Or

If you like to have both and give priority to yours first, then

```
$default_validators = $form['#validate'];
unset($form['#validate']);
$form['#validate'][] = 'zloginsecurity_validators';
foreach ($default_validators as $val) {
  $form['#validate'][] = $val;
}
```

Comment: The first parameter should be Form Element Name, not Form name.

Comment: not working. this is not overwritting my previous message which has been defined in user module

Comment: HituBansal: you should use $form['#validate'][] array as mentioned by @inizio. and before doing that do unset($form['#validate']).

Comment: i done this. not working

Comment: have u done unset($form['#validate']) ??

Comment: no where i need to do unset

Comment: just before you set the value for $form['#validate'], unset it. `unset($form['#validate']); $form['#validate'][] = 'zloginsecurity_validators';`

Comment: If you **unset** $form['#validate'] then the default validation will not work. It is not **prefer** to unset the **default validation**. We are adding **additional validation** for the **existing validate**.

Comment: i am not adding additional validation, jst want to overwrite

Comment: @pown: Can we unset validation above in my code.. as  i need to run this function loginsecurity_validators() { } also here user module is called first

Comment: pls see my updated answer

Comment: This is not working in my code. as i am calling loginsecurity_validators() { }  where some function of core user module is invoke...

Answer (score 2):

Hope this will help you.

In Drupal 7, for validate and to set error you can use these code

`/*
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function zloginsecurity_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  switch ($form_id) {
    case 'user_login':
    case 'user_login_block':
      $form['#validate'][] = 'zloginsecurity_validators';
      break;
  }
}
/*
 * Implements hook_form_validate().
 */
function zloginsecurity_validators($form, &$form_state) {
  if (empty($form_state['values']['uid'])) {//Check user Track Record
    form_set_error('[values][uid', t('hello test'));
  } //do your stuff here
}`

  - You can **Delete Track Records** for Particular user in `hook_form_submit` by using $form_state['values'] array;

Note : Make changes as per  your requirement.

Comment: form_set_error is not working.. it is not showing  hello test

Comment: hey try to print **form_state** using **print_r(form_state)** and check the field name(uid).

Comment: still not working. u also forget to add $ . it must be if(empty(form_state['values']['uid'])) {
} also it will work if we put right password.

Comment: OH! sorry for that. Check for this - if($form_state['values']['uid'] == '') {form_set_error('name', t('hello test')); }

Comment: it will work in all cases. i am not able to login now . using ur code. :)

Comment: The code will just add an **extra validation** for the login and login block forms. Nothing more than that.

Comment: yeah.. but i dnt need this.. dats why i called loginsecurity_validators  function

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9983/discussion-between-inizio-and-hitu-bansal)

Comment: Hey I have updated my answer check it now.  Check this line **form_set_error('[values][uid', t('hello test'))**. Need to use **'[values][uid'** in the form_set_error. It will work.